# How do I configure eclipse to generate a missing method before the current method?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm editing a class in eclipse like this one:

```
class C {
    void m2() {
        m1();
    }
}
```

Eclipse's Quick Fix feature offers to create method `m1()` for me. When I do that, eclipse places `m1()` after `m2()`. Often that's exactly what I want, but sometimes I want eclipse to place the generated method stub before the current method. How do I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately that behavior isn't configurable.

Comment: @E-Riz Do you know of a quick way to move a method up or down in the source?  E.g. one or two keystrokes that would equivalent to cutting a method body and pasting it above the previous method or below the next method.  I haven't found a way besides cut-and-paste.

Comment: whats wrong with a quick cut paste?

Comment: Select the line or lines you want to move, then use Alt+UpArrow and/or  Alt+DownArrow to move the selected line(s). If it's just 1 line you want to move, you don't even have to select it, just place the cursor somewhere in it.

Comment: To select the method quickly while the cursor is in the method use the shortcut for Edit > Expand Selection > Eclosing Element. On Windows this is Shift + Alt + Arrow Up. After that move it around es E-Ri describes.

Comment: right mouse the file in the project explorer, choose Source ! Sort Members...   This will sort the class members alphabetically.